# Batch convert (decode) audio into multiple formats with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, flac, ogg

I have a directory with a bunch of CD quality (16bit 44100Hz) wave-files.

How can I batch decode those into different formats (lets say FLAC, OGG and MP3) using ffmpeg?

---

**Update:** here are the commands one by one as suggested by @StephenHarris

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav output.ogg
ffmpeg -i input.wav output.mp3
ffmpeg -i input.wav output.flac
```

Comment: Take it step by step.  How would you convert _one_ file?  If you can work out how to convert one wav file into flac, into ogg, into mp3 (3 separate commands) then we can add a loop around it.   So "what command would you use to convert wav to flac?"  "what command would convert wav to ogg?"  "What command would convert wav to mp3?"

Comment: @StephenHarris, thanks, just working it out :-)

Comment: @StephenHarris done :-)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ffmpeg` accepts multiple output formats. Set the input file.format with `-i` followed by the output file.format: `ffmpeg -i input.wav output.ogg output.mp3 output.flac`

---

**Batch conversion:**

As a simple one liner with putting each format in a **separate folder:**

```
mkdir mp3 ogg flac; for i in *.wav; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -b:a 320000 "./mp3/${i%.*}.mp3" -b:a 320000 "./ogg/${i%.*}.ogg" "./flac/${i%.*}.flac"; done
```

**Decode all into one folder:**

```
for i in *.wav; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -b:a 320000 "${i%.*}.mp3" -b:a 320000 "${i%.*}.ogg" "${i%.*}.flac"; done
```

`-b:a 320000` sets the bitrate for the decoding of `mp3` and `ogg` and can be adjusted (the bitrate is measured in bits/sec so `320kbit/s` equals `320000`).

---

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147 for the [parameter-expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU Parallel you can run:

```
parallel ffmpeg -i {1} {1.}.{2} ::: *.wav ::: ogg mp3 flac

{1} = replacement string for first input source
{1.} = replacement string for first input source with extension removed
{2} = replacement string for second input source
::: *.wav = input source 1
::: ogg mp3 flac = input source 2
```

This will use all your cores.

Comment: thanks for your reply, would you mind explaining the line?

Comment: whoa...this is the way